# Definition of the Fundamental Class for $K(A,0)$

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

I'm having a little doubts on the definition of the fundamental class for the Eilenberg-MacLane space $K(A,0)$.

Recall that a fundamental class $\imath_{A,n}$ for a polarized $K(A,n)$ is the element of $H^n(K(A,n),A)$ representing $\phi_n\circ H^{-1}$ via the UCT isomorphism. we use it to prove the brown representability theorem for cohomology.

$K(A,0)=:K$ is a discrete set of points of cardinality $|A|$. we have that $$ H^0(K,A) \cong \hom_{\text{Grp}}(H_0(A),A) \cong \text{Map}(A,A)$$ and my definition says to take as $\imath_{A,0}$ the preimage of the identity $Id \colon A \to A$.

So far so good. We want to build now Steenrod squares, defined as

> $Sq^i$ is the unique stable mod-2 cohomology operation such that $Sq^i(x)=x\smile x$ if $x$ has degree $i$.

and I want to prove that $Sq^0=Id$. We know that (by representability) $$H^0(X,\mathbb{F}_2) \cong [X,K(\mathbb{F}_2,0)]_\ast$$ and therefore each $x \in  H^0(X,\mathbb{F}_2)$ can be seen as $f^*(\imath_{\mathbb{F}_2,0})$, for some $f \in [X,K(\mathbb{F}_2,0)]_\ast$. Therefore by naturality it's enough to check if $$ Sq^0(\imath_{\mathbb{F}_2,0})\overset{def}{=} \imath_{\mathbb{F}_2,0}\smile \imath_{\mathbb{F}_2,0} \overset{?}{=} \imath_{\mathbb{F}_2,0}$$

**Here is my problem**, with my definition of fundamental class $\imath_{\mathbb{F}_2,0}$, I really don't know how to show that it is indeed the multiplicative unit. In fact, being the preimage of the identity leads me to think that it is NOT the multiplicative unit, because If my computations are right, being the multiplicative unit would require that evaluated on each chain, it has to be constantly $1$ (multiplicative unit in the coefficient ring).

Anyone knows how to solve this doubt?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right that $\iota_{\mathbb{F}_2,0}$ is not the multiplicative unit.  However, it still is its own square.  Indeed, for any space $X$, *every* element of $H^0(X,\mathbb{F}_2)$ is its own square.  Even more strongly, this holds on the chain level: any singular $0$-cochain on a space with coefficients in $\mathbb{F}_2$ is its own square.  Indeed, a singular $0$-cochain is just a function $c:X\to\mathbb{F}_2$, and the cup product $c\smile c$ is the function $X\to \mathbb{F}_2$ that sends $x$ to $c(x)^2$ (you can see this directly from the definition of the cup product on cochains).  Since every element of $\mathbb{F}_2$ is its own square, $c(x)^2=c(x)$, so $c\smile c=c$.

Comment: Nice! I thought (don't know why) that it has to be something related to the multiplicative unit, because in the argument I had on my notes, everything begins with, "by naturality let us study the case with the classifying object" and this leads me to think that I have to work with specific properties of this guy, and therefore I lose the general vision of what's going on really. Thank you very much!